# What stopwords list is the Wolfram language using?

Tags: string-manipulation, text, implementation-details, linguistics

The documentation of `DeleteStopwords` only says that it "uses a standard, built-in list of stopwords".

So what is it exactly?

---

**Update**

Now that it is said "standard", does that standard have a name?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little spelunking of the code for `DeleteStopwords[]` yields the internally used stopword list:

```
DeleteStopwords; (* force auto-load *)
AlphabeticSort[List @@ TextProcessing`TextModificationDump`$stopWords["English"]] // Short
   {"a", "A", "about", "above", "across", "after", "again", "against", "all", "almost",
    "alone", "along", "already", "also", "although", <<240>>,
    "within", "without", "won't", "would", "wouldn't", "yet", "you", "you'd", "you'll",
    "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves"}
```

Comment: Wow, these are some undocumented functions?

Comment: But your codes merely return `{"English"}` as the result on my machine. Did I miss something?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ One has to evaluate `DeleteStopwords` first. The actual code for `DeleteStopwords` and ``TextProcessing`TextModificationDump`$stopWords`` is stored in a file and is loaded only after `DeleteStopwords` is evaluated in the current session.

Comment: Ah, forgot the autoload. Thanks @Henrik!

Comment: @J.M. Always at your service! =)

Comment: what does <<240>> mean?

Comment: @hanshenrik note the use of  `// Short` at the end of the code provided, since I didn't want to paste the entire list. Thus, only the first few and last few list elements are shown, and the rest are elided. Remove the `// Short` to see the entire list.

Answer (score 15):

The **stop-words are documented** and can be looked up as (see Details section of `WordList`):

```
WordList["Stopwords"]
```

[image]

As it might be subject to change so the output below can get outdated, but you can always run the function `WordList["Stopwords"]`:

> {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","A","about","above","across","after","again","against","all","almost","alone","along","already","also","although","always","am","among","an","and","another","any","anyone","anything","anywhere","are","aren't","around","as","at","b","B","back","be","became","because","become","becomes","been","before","behind","being","below","between","both","but","by","c","C","can","cannot","can't","could","couldn't","d","D","did","didn't","do","does","doesn't","doing","done","don't","down","during","e","E","each","either","enough","even","ever","every","everyone","everything","everywhere","f","F","few","find","first","for","four","from","full","further","g","G","get","give","go","h","H","had","hadn't","has","hasn't","have","haven't","having","he","he'd","he'll","her","here","here's","hers","herself","he's","him","himself","his","how","however","how's","i","I","i'd","if","i'll","i'm","in","interest","into","is","isn't","it","it's","its","itself","i've","j","J","k","K","keep","l","L","last","least","less","let's","m","M","made","many","may","me","might","more","most","mostly","much","must","mustn't","my","myself","n","N","never","next","no","nobody","noone","nor","not","nothing","now","nowhere","o","O","of","off","often","on","once","one","only","or","other","others","ought","our","ours","ourselves","out","over","own","p","P","part","per","perhaps","put","q","Q","r","R","rather","s","S","same","see","seem","seemed","seeming","seems","several","shan't","she","she'd","she'll","she's","should","shouldn't","show","side","since","so","some","someone","something","somewhere","still","such","t","T","take","than","that","that's","the","their","theirs","them","themselves","then","there","therefore","there's","these","they","they'd","they'll","they're","they've","this","those","though","three","through","thus","to","together","too","toward","two","u","U","under","until","up","upon","us","v","V","very","w","W","was","wasn't","we","we'd","we'll","well","we're","were","weren't","we've","what","what's","when","when's","where","where's","whether","which","while","who","whole","whom","who's","whose","why","why's","will","with","within","without","won't","would","wouldn't","x","X","y","Y","yet","you","you'd","you'll","your","you're","yours","yourself","yourselves","you've","z","Z"}

Comment: Interestingly, the complement of this list and the list in my answer yields only a list of letters and numbers, so that list certainly captures all the words. However, applying `DeleteStopwords[]` seems to only remove `"i"` from the list.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. a few inconsistencies are known, hopefully will be polished. Important thing is --- the docs is open about the subject, good thing to know :-) The docs is an attractor of stability in terms of known things of internal architecture.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a longer list using the following commands:

```
A = WordList["KnownWords"];
B = DeleteStopwords[A];
c = Complement[A, B]
```

> {
>           a,
>           A,
>           about,
>           above,
>           across,
>           A.D.,
>           add-in,
>           add-on,
>           A.E.,
>           after,
>           again,
>           against,
>           a.k.a.,
>           all,
>           all-around,
>           all-or-nothing,
>           all-out,
>           almost,
>           alone,
>           along,
>           al-Qur'an,
>           already,
>           also,
>           although,
>           always,
>           a.m.,
>           A.M.,
>           Am,
>           AM,
>           among,
>           an,
>           AN,
>           and,
>           and/or,
>           another,
>           any,
>           anyone,
>           anything,
>           anywhere,
>           A-one,
>           are,
>           around,
>           as,
>           As,
>           AS,
>           at,
>           At,
>           back,
>           back-to-back,
>           balls-up,
>           bang-up,
>           be,
>           Be,
>           beaten-up,
>           beat-up,
>           because,
>           become,
>           beefed-up,
>           before,
>           behind,
>           being,
>           belly-up,
>           below,
>           between,
>           bicycle-built-for-two,
>           blown-up,
>           booze-up,
>           born-again,
>           both,
>           bottom-up,
>           boxed-in,
>           break-in,
>           bride-to-be,
>           broken-down,
>           brush-off,
>           built-in,
>           built-up,
>           bundled-up,
>           burned-out,
>           burned-over,
>           burnt-out,
>           bust-up,
>           but,
>           button-down,
>           buttoned-down,
>           buttoned-up,
>           by,
>           by-and-by,
>           call-back,
>           caller-out,
>           caller-up,
>           call-in,
>           call-out,
>           camp-made,
>           can,
>           can-do,
>           cared-for,
>           carry-over,
>           cast-off,
>           change-up,
>           check-in,
>           ch'i,
>           Ch'in,
>           chin-up,
>           chock-full,
>           choke-full,
>           chucker-out,
>           chuck-full,
>           churned-up,
>           climb-down,
>           clip-on,
>           coach-and-four,
>           comb-out,
>           come-on,
>           cover-up,
>           crack-up,
>           cure-all,
>           custom-made,
>           cut-in,
>           cut-up,
>           D.A.,
>           dead-on,
>           derring-do,
>           do,
>           DO,
>           d.o.a.,
>           do-it-yourself,
>           done,
>           do-nothing,
>           do-si-do,
>           down,
>           Down,
>           down-and-out,
>           drawn-out,
>           dressed-up,
>           dried-out,
>           dried-up,
>           drive-in,
>           drop-off,
>           during,
>           each,
>           eighty-four,
>           eighty-one,
>           eighty-three,
>           eighty-two,
>           either,
>           end-all,
>           enough,
>           even,
>           ever,
>           every,
>           everyone,
>           everything,
>           everywhere,
>           eyes-only,
>           face-off,
>           factory-made,
>           fare-thee-well,
>           far-off,
>           far-out,
>           few,
>           fifty-four,
>           fifty-one,
>           fifty-three,
>           fifty-two,
>           fill-in,
>           find,
>           first,
>           F.I.S.C.,
>           flame-out,
>           flare-up,
>           fly-by,
>           follow-on,
>           follow-through,
>           follow-up,
>           for,
>           force-out,
>           fore-and-after,
>           forget-me-not,
>           form-only,
>           forty-first,
>           forty-four,
>           forty-one,
>           forty-three,
>           forty-two,
>           foul-up,
>           four,
>           frame-up,
>           free-for-all,
>           from,
>           fucked-up,
>           full,
>           further,
>           get,
>           get-go,
>           get-up-and-go,
>           G.I.,
>           gill-less,
>           give,
>           give-and-go,
>           give-and-take,
>           go,
>           go-around,
>           go-between,
>           going-over,
>           good-by,
>           good-for-nothing,
>           goof-off,
>           groom-to-be,
>           half-seas-over,
>           hand-down,
>           handed-down,
>           hand-me-down,
>           hands-down,
>           hands-off,
>           hands-on,
>           hanger-on,
>           hang-up,
>           hard-on,
>           has-been,
>           have,
>           have-not,
>           Hawai'i,
>           he,
>           He,
>           head-on,
>           heads-up,
>           heart-whole,
>           her,
>           here,
>           Here,
>           hers,
>           herself,
>           higher-up,
>           high-interest,
>           high-up,
>           him,
>           himself,
>           his,
>           hold-down,
>           hollow-back,
>           hoped-for,
>           hopped-up,
>           how,
>           how-do-you-do,
>           how-d'ye-do,
>           however,
>           HSV-I,
>           hundred-and-first,
>           hushed-up,
>           i,
>           I,
>           I.D.,
>           i.e.,
>           I.E.D.,
>           if,
>           If,
>           ill-being,
>           in,
>           In,
>           IN,
>           in-between,
>           inside-out,
>           interest,
>           into,
>           I.Q.,
>           it,
>           IT,
>           its,
>           itself,
>           I.W.W.,
>           jerk-off,
>           Johnny-jump-up,
>           jumped-up,
>           keep,
>           knock-down,
>           knock-down-and-drag-out,
>           knocked-out,
>           know-all,
>           know-how,
>           know-it-all,
>           ladder-back,
>           laid-back,
>           laid-off,
>           lash-up,
>           last,
>           lay-by,
>           lay-up,
>           lead-in,
>           lean-to,
>           least,
>           less,
>           lie-in,
>           lighting-up,
>           lights-out,
>           log-in,
>           longed-for,
>           looker-on,
>           look-over,
>           low-down,
>           low-interest,
>           lying-in,
>           ma'am,
>           machine-made,
>           made,
>           made-up,
>           make-do,
>           make-up,
>           man-made,
>           many,
>           marked-up,
>           match-up,
>           matt-up,
>           may,
>           May,
>           me,
>           ME,
>           mess-up,
>           mid-May,
>           mid-off,
>           mid-on,
>           might,
>           might-have-been,
>           mixed-up,
>           mix-up,
>           mock-up,
>           more,
>           More,
>           most,
>           mostly,
>           much,
>           must,
>           my,
>           myself,
>           ne'er-do-well,
>           never,
>           never-never,
>           Never-Never,
>           new-made,
>           next,
>           next-to-last,
>           ninety-four,
>           ninety-one,
>           ninety-three,
>           ninety-two,
>           no,
>           No,
>           no.,
>           nobody,
>           no-go,
>           no-one,
>           nor,
>           no-show,
>           nosh-up,
>           not,
>           nothing,
>           now,
>           nowhere,
>           odds-on,
>           of,
>           off,
>           off-and-on,
>           often,
>           on,
>           once,
>           once-over,
>           one,
>           one-and-one,
>           one-off,
>           one-on-one,
>           one-to-one,
>           only,
>           OR,
>           other,
>           our,
>           ours,
>           ourselves,
>           out,
>           out-and-out,
>           over,
>           own,
>           p.a.,
>           P.A.,
>           paid-up,
>           part,
>           passer-by,
>           pass-through,
>           paste-up,
>           pegged-down,
>           pent-up,
>           per,
>           perhaps,
>           phase-out,
>           phone-in,
>           pick-me-up,
>           pick-off,
>           pig-a-back,
>           pin-up,
>           piss-up,
>           plug-in,
>           pop-up,
>           Post-It,
>           press-up,
>           pull-in,
>           pull-off,
>           pull-through,
>           pull-up,
>           pumped-up,
>           punch-up,
>           purpose-made,
>           put,
>           put-down,
>           put-on,
>           put-put,
>           put-up,
>           put-upon,
>           rake-off,
>           raree-show,
>           rather,
>           rave-up,
>           read-out,
>           ready-made,
>           right-down,
>           right-side-out,
>           right-side-up,
>           rip-off,
>           roll-on,
>           run-down,
>           run-in,
>           runner-up,
>           run-on,
>           run-through,
>           run-up,
>           same,
>           Same,
>           Sana'a,
>           sauce-alone,
>           save-all,
>           sawed-off,
>           sawn-off,
>           say-so,
>           schoolma'am,
>           see,
>           seem,
>           seeming,
>           see-through,
>           self-interest,
>           self-made,
>           self-will,
>           send-off,
>           set-back,
>           set-to,
>           seventy-four,
>           seventy-one,
>           seventy-three,
>           seventy-two,
>           seven-up,
>           several,
>           shake-up,
>           shape-up,
>           share-out,
>           she,
>           shell-less,
>           shoo-in,
>           shoot-down,
>           shoot-'em-up,
>           show,
>           show-off,
>           shut-in,
>           side,
>           side-to-side,
>           since,
>           sit-down,
>           sit-in,
>           sit-up,
>           sixty-four,
>           sixty-one,
>           sixty-three,
>           sixty-two,
>           slap-up,
>           slip-on,
>           slip-up,
>           smash-up,
>           snarl-up,
>           so,
>           so-and-so,
>           sold-out,
>           some,
>           someone,
>           something,
>           somewhere,
>           so-so,
>           sought-after,
>           spaced-out,
>           spend-all,
>           spin-off,
>           spread-out,
>           stand-alone,
>           stand-down,
>           stand-in,
>           stand-up,
>           start-off,
>           step-down,
>           step-in,
>           step-up,
>           stick-on,
>           still,
>           stock-still,
>           stock-take,
>           stopped-up,
>           straight-out,
>           stripped-down,
>           strung-out,
>           stuck-up,
>           such,
>           sum-up,
>           sure-enough,
>           tailor-made,
>           take,
>           take-in,
>           take-up,
>           tap-off,
>           teach-in,
>           than,
>           that,
>           the,
>           their,
>           theirs,
>           them,
>           themselves,
>           then,
>           there,
>           therefore,
>           these,
>           they,
>           thing-in-itself,
>           thirty-first,
>           thirty-four,
>           thirty-one,
>           thirty-something,
>           thirty-three,
>           thirty-two,
>           this,
>           those,
>           though,
>           three,
>           through,
>           throw-in,
>           thus,
>           tie-in,
>           tie-on,
>           tie-up,
>           time-out,
>           tip-off,
>           tip-up,
>           to,
>           to-do,
>           toe-in,
>           together,
>           too,
>           top-down,
>           top-up,
>           toss-up,
>           touch-and-go,
>           touch-me-not,
>           toward,
>           trade-in,
>           trade-last,
>           trade-off,
>           tricked-out,
>           trip-up,
>           trumped-up,
>           try-on,
>           tumble-down,
>           tune-up,
>           turn-on,
>           twenty-first,
>           twenty-four,
>           twenty-one,
>           twenty-three,
>           twenty-two,
>           two,
>           two-by-four,
>           two-part,
>           uncalled-for,
>           uncared-for,
>           under,
>           unheard-of,
>           unhoped-for,
>           unlooked-for,
>           unthought-of,
>           until,
>           unwished-for,
>           up,
>           up-and-down,
>           upon,
>           upside-down,
>           us,
>           US,
>           U.S.A.,
>           very,
>           walk-in,
>           walk-on,
>           walk-through,
>           walk-to,
>           walk-up,
>           warm-up,
>           washed-out,
>           washed-up,
>           washing-up,
>           wave-off,
>           way-out,
>           we,
>           well,
>           well-being,
>           well-done,
>           well-made,
>           well-off,
>           well-thought-of,
>           well-to-do,
>           what,
>           when,
>           where,
>           where's,
>           whether,
>           which,
>           while,
>           whipper-in,
>           white-out,
>           who,
>           WHO,
>           whole,
>           whom,
>           whose,
>           why,
>           will,
>           wished-for,
>           with,
>           within,
>           with-it,
>           without,
>           work-in,
>           worn-out,
>           would-be,
>           write-down,
>           write-in,
>           write-off,
>           wrong-side-out,
>           year-around,
>           yearned-for,
>           yet,
>           you,
>           you-all,
>           your,
>           yours,
>           yourself
>       }

Comment: Why uppercase `A` and `B`, but lowercase `c`?

Comment: What this longer list actually demonstrates is what could be called a peculiarity in `DeleteStopwords[]`: `DeleteStopwords["ne'er-do-well wearing buttoned-down vests"]`

Answer (score 6):

Another way

```
WordData[All, "Stopwords"] == WordList["Stopwords"]
```

> True