# Commonest[] function doesn't actually show commonest elements

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, filtering

I'm using `Commonest` function on a list with 500000 words to get the 10 most frequent elements. Then by using `WordCloud`, I found out that the most frequent word is actually `"far"`, and then checked it by `StringCount`. So the thing I would like to know is why results from `WordCloud` and `Commonest` are so different, and how to make `Commonest` work properly?

[File with words I used](https://ufile.io/naunk), also [here](https://pastebin.com/Z0hd3huU)

(Sorry for all mistakes, English is only my 3rd language..)

[image: session]

Comment: It's because "far" is a part of many of the words, e.g., "afar", "farsighted", "airfare", etc.

Comment: I removed the [tag:bugs] tag _for now_, in accordance with the tag description.

Comment: @CarlWoll `Commonest` definitely works correctly (can be verified with `Counts`/`Tally`).  As for the `WordCloud` behaviour, I'm very sceptical about this, I would not consider it correct ... bug?

Comment: @Szabolcs The bug is within `DeleteStopwords`, if it is a bug - I show it at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: It seems to me like `DeleteStopwords`, which `WordCloud` uses by default, is deleting a lot of words that it ought not be deleting, such as "custom-made", "runner-up", "interest" and so on (`Complement[TextWords[txt], TextWords[DeleteStopwords[txt]]]`). Perhaps it would be good to report this to WRI and see if they consider it a bug. OP, I would rename this question something like "WordCloud processes input text badly".

Comment: Ah, to follow up, `DeleteStopwords` is actually deleting "custom-**made**", which is then segmented to "custom". `DeleteStopwords` probably should not delete parts of hyphenated words - that sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using [`TextWords`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextWords.html) to segment your data into words. Things like `StringCount[data, "far"]` will also count "**far**t".

```
Commonest[TextWords[txt], 10]
```

> `{"affirm", "calligrapher", "squander", "validly", "autoimmune", "equation", "nematode", "veronica", "crispness", "ashen"}`

```
WordCloud[TextWords[txt]]
```

[image]

You can use [`Counts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html) to get the counts of each word as well:

```
TakeLargest[Counts[TextWords[txt]], 20]
```

> `<|"affirm" -> 29, "equation" -> 28, "veronica" -> 28, "ashen" -> 28, 
>    "crispness" -> 28, "knacker" -> 27, "validly" -> 27, 
>    "squander" -> 27, "nematode" -> 27, "autoimmune" -> 27, 
>    "calligrapher" -> 27, "pus" -> 26, "sledding" -> 26, 
>    "tablecloth" -> 26, "inclusive" -> 26, "variegated" -> 26, 
>    "gastrointestinal" -> 26, "undercoat" -> 26, "washout" -> 26, 
>    "reconnoitering" -> 26|>`

It seems to me that the issue with [`WordCloud`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordCloud.html) is actually an issue within [`DeleteStopwords`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteStopwords.html), which `WordCloud` is using internally when the input is a string.

[image]

You can prevent `WordCloud` from using `DeleteStopwords` by passing `PreprocessingRules -> None`:

[image]

It seems to me that `DeleteStopwords` is deleting many words that perhaps it shouldn't be:

```
Complement[TextWords[txt], TextWords[DeleteStopwords[txt]]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "about", "above", "across", "add-on", "after", "again", \
> "against", "all", "almost", "alone", "along", "already", "also", \
> "although", "always", "among", "an", "and", "another", "any", \
> "anyone", "anything", "anywhere", "are", "around", "as", "at", \
> "back", "back-to-back", "be", "because", "become", "before", \
> "behind", "being", "below", "between", "born-again", "both", \
> "built-in", "but", "by", "can-do", "custom-made", "do", "done", \
> "down", "during", "each", "either", "enough", "even", "ever", \
> "every", "everyone", "everything", "everywhere", "far-off", \
> "far-out", "few", "find", "first", "for", "four", "from", "full", \
> "further", "get", "give", "go", "have-not", "he", "head-on", "her", \
> "here", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "however", \
> "if", "in", "interest", "into", "it", "its", "itself", "keep", \
> "laid-back", "last", "least", "less", "ma'am", "made", "man-made", \
> "many", "may", "me", "might", "more", "most", "mostly", "much", \
> "must", "my", "myself", "never", "next", "nobody", "nor", "no-show", \
> "not", "nothing", "now", "nowhere", "of", "off", "often", "on", \
> "once", "one", "only", "other", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", \
> "over", "own", "part", "per", "perhaps", "put", "rather", \
> "runner-up", "same", "seem", "seeming", "see-through", \
> "self-interest", "self-made", "several", "she", "show", "side", \
> "since", "sit-in", "so", "some", "someone", "something", "somewhere", \
> "still", "such", "take", "than", "that", "the", "their", "theirs", \
> "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "therefore", "these", "they", \
> "this", "those", "though", "three", "through", "thus", "to", \
> "together", "too", "toward", "two", "under", "until", "up", "upon", \
> "us", "very", "we", "well", "well-to-do", "what", "when", "where", \
> "where's", "whether", "which", "while", "who", "whole", "whom", \
> "whose", "why", "will", "with", "within", "without", "would-be", \
> "write-off", "yet", "you", "your", "yours", "yourself"}
> ```

I agree with some of those stopwords, but not really any of them that contain the `-` character. This is perhaps where the issue lies.

What appears to be happening is that `DeleteStopwords` is deleting *part* of some words, and what's left over is counted. We can see the outcome:

```
Counts[TextWords[txt]]["far"]
```

> `19`

```
Counts[TextWords[DeleteStopwords[txt]]]["far"]
```

> `39`

We can see that this behaviour is weird by comparing the following:

```
Select[TextWords[txt], StringStartsQ["far"]] // Counts // ReverseSort
```

> `<|"farinaceous" -> 19, "far" -> 19, "fare" -> 19, "faro" -> 18, 
>    "farther" -> 17, "farmer" -> 17, "farcical" -> 17, "farthing" -> 17, 
>    "faraway" -> 16, "farmstead" -> 16, "farrier" -> 15, 
>    "farthermost" -> 14, "far-off" -> 14, "farming" -> 14, 
>    "farrago" -> 13, "farm" -> 13, "farcically" -> 13, "farrowing" -> 12,
>     "farce" -> 11, "farsighted" -> 11, "farmland" -> 10, 
>    "farsightedness" -> 10, "farmhouse" -> 9, "farseeing" -> 9, 
>    "farad" -> 8, "farina" -> 8, "farthest" -> 8, "farmhand" -> 7, 
>    "farewell" -> 7, "farrow" -> 6, "farmyard" -> 6, "far-out" -> 6|>`

```
Select[TextWords[DeleteStopwords@txt], StringStartsQ["far"]] // Counts // ReverseSort
```

> `<|"far" -> 39, "farinaceous" -> 19, "fare" -> 19, "faro" -> 18, 
>    "farther" -> 17, "farmer" -> 17, "farcical" -> 17, "farthing" -> 17, 
>    "faraway" -> 16, "farmstead" -> 16, "farrier" -> 15, 
>    "farthermost" -> 14, "farming" -> 14, "farrago" -> 13, "farm" -> 13, 
>    "farcically" -> 13, "farrowing" -> 12, "farce" -> 11, 
>    "farsighted" -> 11, "farmland" -> 10, "farsightedness" -> 10, 
>    "farmhouse" -> 9, "farseeing" -> 9, "farad" -> 8, "farina" -> 8, 
>    "farthest" -> 8, "farmhand" -> 7, "farewell" -> 7, "farrow" -> 6, 
>    "farmyard" -> 6|>`

Here we can see that `DeleteStopwords` is replacing "far-out" and "far-off" with "far-", which is segmented to "far" by `TextWords`, which completely throws off WordCloud's counting mechanism in this case.

Comment: What you observed about `DeleteStopwords[]` is the same issue I touched on [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182531/what-stopwords-list-is-the-wolfram-language-using/182579#comment476557_182578).

Answer (score 4):

As already noted by Carl, you have blamed the wrong function. Had you imported the text file in the proper format, you would have gotten the expected results:

```
words = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/Z0hd3huU", "List"];

AllTrue[words, StringQ]
   True

Take[words, 10]
   {"inconsiderate", "weighting", "unneeded", "issuing", "intemperately", "perverse",
    "disgruntled", "ninja", "artificially", "seduce"}
```

Note that this import format already yielded a list of strings as opposed to a single string.

```
Commonest[words, 10]
   {"affirm", "calligrapher", "squander", "validly", "autoimmune", "equation", "nematode",
    "veronica", "crispness", "ashen"}

TakeLargest[Counts[words], 10]
   <|"affirm" -> 29, "equation" -> 28, "ashen" -> 28, "crispness" -> 28, "veronica" -> 28,
     "squander" -> 27, "validly" -> 27, "calligrapher" -> 27, "autoimmune" -> 27,
     "nematode" -> 27|>

WordCloud[words]
```

[image: word cloud]